# Conditional Formatting to apply colour of the formatted cell to the column referenced in that cell (variable cells & range)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'll be applying this formatting as VBA but for now just need to know how it can work.

I have a range and each cell in that range is to have a column letter inputted. When that letter is inputted I want the first cell (row 1) in the referenced column to be coloured the same as the cell in the range where I have inputted the letter. So, I input B into the formatted cell (which is coloured red, and cell B1 is coloured red, the same as the formatted cell.

To complicate matters, each sheet this is to be used on is different so the numbers of columns, referenced column numbers and the range location are different each time.

To begin with I am not even sure if I need to format the cell in the range or the cell in the referenced column.

Can anyone help with a way I can conditionally format a cell (either in the range or in the referenced column) that will perform this function please?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying I don't think you can do this without saving the file as .xlsm but you can do this without VBA. You can use the old Excel 4 macro GET.CELL in a named range to return the cell color i.e. see here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color
```

Then use that result as input for a conditional formatting custom formula to format those destination columns. Take great care here, as both get.cell and CF are volatile and will make your work slow (especially if its a large workbook).

If you do want to use VBA, have a look here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520570/return-background-color-of-selected-cell
```